# How to use fs.createWriteStream to update an individual row

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, fs

I'm using the following logic, but not able to update a csv at a paricular row. What am I missing to allow a row number to be passed into the `options` object?

```js
let stream =  fs.createWriteStream(
  filePathVariable,
  {
    start: csvRowNumberVariable //isn't this where the row number should 'start' at?
  }
);
stream.write(data);
stream.end();
stream.on('finish',() => {
  console.log('finished')
  resolve();
});
```

Comment: Isn't csv comms separated values? Str they also separated by spaces or new line characters?

Comment: `start: csvRowNumberVariable //isn't this where the row number should 'start' at?` -- absolutely not. A write stream is a byte stream. It has no concept of rows. `start` is the byte where to start, not the row.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I appreciate the clarification. If you can help me understand the core concept to resolve my issue I would really appreciate it.